# Vue Js: Sonar complains Either remove this useless object instantiation of "Vue" or use it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

So I have a vue js snippet something like this:

```
new Vue({
      el: elem,
      render: function (h) {
        return h('inputString', {
          //some code
        });
      },
    });
```

Sonar complains that

*Either remove this useless object instantiation of "Vue" or use it.*

Which actually makes sense if we see that we're creating an instance of object but we're not using it. However, that's how a component is instantiated in vue. So Do I resolve that as 'won't fix' or is there anything that we can do here.

I also thought about the assigning to another variable.

```
 var vm = new Vue({
      el: elem,
      render: function (h) {
        return h('inputString', {
          //some code
        });
      },
    });
```

But then it will complain about `vm` not being unused.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid marking the issue as 'won't fix', you can use your Vue instance in the following way:

```
 var vm = new Vue({
      render: function (h) {
        return h('inputString', {
          //some code
        });
      },
    });
 vm.$mount(elem)
```

- [Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount)